# how do I get the latest document grouped by a field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an `index` with many `documents` in this format:

```
{
    "userId": 1234,
    "locationDate" "2016-07-19T19:24:51+0000",
    "location": {
        "lat": -47.38163,
        "lon": 26.38916
    }
}
```

In this index I have incremental positions from the user, updated every few seconds.

I would like to execute a search that would return me the latest position (sorted by `locationDate`) from each user (grouped by `userId`)

Is this possible with elastic search? the best I could do was get all the positions from the last 30 seconds, using this:

```
{"query":{
  "filtered" : {
    "query" : {
      "match_all" : { }
    },
    "filter" : {
      "range" : {
        "locationDate" : {
          "from" : "2016-07-19T18:54:51+0000",
          "to" : null,
          "include_lower" : true,
          "include_upper" : true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

And then after that I sort them out by hand, but I would like to do this directly on elastic search

**IMPORTANT:** I am using elasticsearch 1.5.2

Answer (score 1):

Try this (with aggregations):

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "locationDate": {
            "from": "2016-07-19T18:54:51+0000",
            "to": null,
            "include_lower": true,
            "include_upper": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "byUser": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userId",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "firstOne": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "locationDate": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the `order` is failing. Is that the correct syntax? I get this message: "AggregationExecutionException[Invalid term-aggregator order path [locationDate]. Unknown aggregation [locationDate]]}]"

Comment: Sorry about that. I blindly provided that. I updated the answer with something that should work.